# How to get correct Cell reference in excel worksheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel worksheet i use to create a coverage matrix for test planning.  requirements v testcase.

I have been trying to use the formula below to return the correct cell reference (eg cell d10 for example) whereever a cell has a tick in my worksheet selected range but using the formula below whilst i get the right row number the column name is always given as A

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("P",C7:DB7,FALSE)),"NO",CELL("address"))
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking across a row for a match. Why would the 'address' be three rows down?

Comment: Is your formula in Column A by any chance?....

Comment: Hi.  It is in column A.

Answer (score 0):

The `CELL("address")` function will return the address that the formula is in.

The quick and dirty solution to your question is the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("P",C7:DB7,0)),"NO",ADDRESS(7,MATCH("P",C7:DB7,0)+2))
```

Note that `7` and `+2` are hardcoded because your range is in column C and row 7

This will only find the address of the first tick

Comment: Hi Callum. Basically in my spreadsheet i have a number of columns (over a 200 columns) 1 column for each new testcases and each row has a requirement. I have put these in column B. Column C contains the first TestCase for my coverage matirx. I have several of these matrixes to track hence the need for this formula. What I was trying to do was every time i create a script i would put a tick in the appropriate column.  Using the hardcoded7 and 2 in the formula does not work.   What i want the formula to do is look across the selected row & return row  number and Column letter containg tick.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using callumDA33 solution i changed 7 to read Row() and that worked i am now getting correct row and column

so solution looks like =IF(ISERROR(MATCH("P",C3:AH3,0)),"NO",ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH("P",C3:AH3)+2))